# Necessary to wrap all javascript in a try-catch block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have noticed that some of the javascript files included in my manifest file are not running. I believe this is because an exception is being thrown in one of the files higher on the manifest list, so the code in the files below it is not being run in application.js.

Does this explanation make sense?  I have only noticed this since upgrading to Rails 3.2.11.

Should I be wrapping the code in each of the individual files in a try catch block? What is the best way of dealing with this issue?

Most of the code uses jquery and is adding handlers to document.ready.

Comment: Start by looking at the javascript console.

Comment: Do you see them included when you view source?

Comment: @99miles Yes both files are included. The second one is never run. When I swap them it works. An exception is thrown in the first one because the page doesn't contain the element it is looking for.

Comment: then guard that clause (for the element), not the whole thing